# prevent a job in github action workflow file to run in case of an event

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a github action workflow validate which currently runs on

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, edited]
```

there are multiple jobs in this workflow - but for the 1st job - I don't want it to run when a PR is edited.

Hence I've written something like:

```
jobs:
  run_tests:
    name: Run Tests
    continue-on-error: false
    if: github.event.pull_request.edited != true
```

But this is not working - when I edit the pull request - the 1st job starts running...

I had even tried with

```
if: github.event.pull_request.action != 'edited'
```

How can I prevent this sub-job from running only for a specific pull_request event.

Thanks again
Prabhas

Answer (score 2):

After making some tests, I observed that you need another syntax to check the pull request event type.

I actually had to use `${{ github.event.action }}`

**Example:**

```
if: github.event.action == 'edited'
```

To do so, I checked the GITHUB CONTEXT inside the workflow run (you can see the logs [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/8248357033?check_suite_focus=true)) and observed that the event actually appears like this:

```
{
  [...]
  "base_ref": "main",
  "event_name": "pull_request",
  "event": {
    "action": "edited",
    [...]
  }
}
```

Where this `event.action` field would change according to the type (for example, you will have a *"synchronize"* there, if you update the PR files or description).

I made a full workflow example [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/test55/.github/workflows/workflow-tester55.yml) if you want to check, with [this workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/3014773839) (when edited), and this other [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/8248340412) (when synchronized).